# How do I fill time sequence based on start and end time in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to fill the time-sequence based on start and end of time. Here is the dataset.

> structure(list(type = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label
>   = c("",  "end_time", "start_time"), class = "factor"), col1 = structure(c(2L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "2019-07-07
>   21:53:00",  "2019-07-07 21:53:40", "2019-07-07 21:54:40", "2019-07-07
>   21:56:00" ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
>   4L,  4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "VALUE_1", "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3"), class =
>   "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -7L))

```
        type                col1   value
1 start_time 2019-07-07 21:53:00 VALUE_1
2   end_time 2019-07-07 21:53:40 VALUE_1
3 start_time 2019-07-07 21:53:40 VALUE_2
4   end_time 2019-07-07 21:54:40 VALUE_2
5 start_time 2019-07-07 21:54:40 VALUE_3
6   end_time 2019-07-07 21:56:00 VALUE_3
```

After setting an interval to fill the sequence, I want to make the filled sequence. For example, in case of 20-seconds, this is my expected table.

```
col1                 value
2019-07-07 21:53:00 VALUE_1
2019-07-07 21:53:20 VALUE_1
2019-07-07 21:53:40 VALUE_1
2019-07-07 21:53:40 VALUE_2
2019-07-07 21:54:00 VALUE_2
2019-07-07 21:54:20 VALUE_2
2019-07-07 21:54:40 VALUE_2
2019-07-07 21:54:40 VALUE_3
2019-07-07 21:54:00 VALUE_3
2019-07-07 21:55:20 VALUE_3
2019-07-07 21:55:40 VALUE_3
2019-07-07 21:56:00 VALUE_3
```

How should I make the table using dplyr?

Comment: I will check the question. Thanks!!

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this on SO. I am sure you'll find one that meets your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "close-as-dupe" might win, but I think the solutions are a little off in that they don't address the grouping of it. (Note that I adjusted the data, because (1) those aren't `POSIXt`, and (2) there's an empty bottom row.)

Here's a solution (that starts with the assumption that you have no other columns to preserve, just the start/end times and the `value`):

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  do( data.frame(time = do.call(seq.POSIXt, c(as.list(sort(range(.$col1))), by = 20))) ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    value   time                   
#    <fct>   <dttm>                 
#  1 VALUE_1 2019-07-07 21:53:00.000
#  2 VALUE_1 2019-07-07 21:53:20.000
#  3 VALUE_1 2019-07-07 21:53:40.000
#  4 VALUE_2 2019-07-07 21:53:40.000
#  5 VALUE_2 2019-07-07 21:54:00.000
#  6 VALUE_2 2019-07-07 21:54:20.000
#  7 VALUE_2 2019-07-07 21:54:40.000
#  8 VALUE_3 2019-07-07 21:54:40.000
#  9 VALUE_3 2019-07-07 21:55:00.000
# 10 VALUE_3 2019-07-07 21:55:20.000
# 11 VALUE_3 2019-07-07 21:55:40.000
# 12 VALUE_3 2019-07-07 21:56:00.000
```

Unraveling just a little:

- `group_by` does this once for `VALUE_1` times, etc;
- `sort(range(.$col1))` just finds the two outer times (which happen to be start/end times, but I'm ignoring that for this solution) ... sorting it is just defensive, as I don't know if you assume and can guarantee that the order is always correct;
- `do.call` combines all arguments into a list (formed by the result of `range()` and adds a third argument `by=20` for 20-second spacing), and passes this list of arguments do `seq.POSIXt` ... *For example*, if the `range` returns `time1` and `time2`, then the whole `do.call(seq.POSIXt, c(...))` is analogous to `seq.POSIXt(time1, time2, by=20)`.

In `dplyr`'s grouping, the `do` block effectively replaces the incoming-frame with what we generate inside the `do` block, which is a frame of "some length" (based on the start/end times and `by=` interval). Because grouping always preserves the grouping variable, `value` persists and is repeated across all returned rows.

Alternatively, a `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)
xDT <- copy(x)
setDT(xDT)
xDT[, .(time = do.call(seq.POSIXt, c(as.list(sort(range(col1))), by = 20))), by = "value"]
```

---

Data:

```r
x <- structure(list(type = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "end_time", "start_time"), class = "factor"), col1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "2019-07-07 21:53:00", "2019-07-07 21:53:40", "2019-07-07 21:54:40", "2019-07-07 21:56:00" ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "VALUE_1", "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
x$col1 <- as.POSIXct(x$col1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
x <- x[!is.na(x$col1),]
```

Comment: An alternative to the `do` construct is to use `tidyr::complete`: `df %>% mutate(col1 = as.POSIXct(col1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>% group_by(value) %>% complete(col1 = seq(col1[1], col1[2], by = 20))`

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers, and that's even one of the answers in the other ... I am not as familiar with `complete`, I'll try to absorb it into my habits. Thanks! (The fact that I don't know it is why I did not recognize that it was applicable here.)

Comment: Ah yes, I saw that too late:-)

Answer (score 1):

This uses @r2evan's dataset - the original has a `NA` value which messes up things.

```
library(dplyr)
library (tidyr)
vec_seq <- Vectorize(seq.POSIXt, , vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

x%>%
  spread(key = 'type', value = 'col1' )%>%
  transmute(value, col1 = vec_seq(start_time, end_time, 20))%>%
  unnest()
```

Data, again @r2evan:

```
x <- structure(list(type = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "end_time", "start_time"), class = "factor"), col1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "2019-07-07 21:53:00", "2019-07-07 21:53:40", "2019-07-07 21:54:40", "2019-07-07 21:56:00" ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "VALUE_1", "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
x$col1 <- as.POSIXct(x$col1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
x <- x[!is.na(x$col1),]
```